# 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread' error in prepareForSegue; Swift

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, grand-central-dispatch, realm

What am I doing wrong that would cause a 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread' error?

```
    2015-03-14 06:59:54.962 MyApp[25646:1218284] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01961466 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01212a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   MyApp                         0x00120329 _ZL11RLMGetArrayP13RLMObjectBasejP8NSString + 382
    3   MyApp                         0x00122952 ___ZL17RLMAccessorGetterP11RLMPropertycP8NSString_block_invoke291 + 25
    4   MyApp                         0x00047f87 _TFFC11 MyApp 25ReadArticleViewController11viewDidLoadFS0_FT_T_U_FT_T_ + 823
    5   MyApp                         0x0003da44 _TPA__TFFC11 MyApp 25ReadArticleViewController11viewDidLoadFS0_FT_T_U_FT_T_ + 52
    6   MyApp                         0x0004bce8 _TTRXFo__dT__XFdCb__dT__ + 40
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0384eaf8 _dispatch_block_async_invoke_and_release + 347
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0386dbef _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x038551ef _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1092
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03856b70 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 115
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x03bc91da _pthread_wqthread + 724
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x03bc6e2e start_wqthread + 30
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here is my prepareForSegue?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        if segue.identifier == "readArticle" {

            let indexPathRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row// because I need to show a progress view whie the next view loads // sometimes it works.

            Async.background {
                println("BEFORE")
                var Realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
                if let article = Article.allObjects()[UInt(indexPathRow)] as? Article
                {
                    var destination = segue.destinationViewController as ReadArticleViewController
                    destination.article = article as Article
//                  destination.realmQueue = self.realmQueue as dispatch_queue_attr_t
                }
                println("AFTER")

            }.main {
                println("finished segue")
            }
        }
        else if segue.identifier == "newArticle" {
//          let newArticleViewController = segue.destinationViewController as NewArticleViewController
        }

    }
```

Sometimes I make it to the next view and sometimes not.

Is there anyway to guarantee what thread will be used so I can make sure to use the same one each time I access the realm?

What else am I doing wrong to cause this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the crash happens because you're trying to use an article from a "background accessed Realm" in the ReadArticleViewController's viewDidLoad method which is called in the main thread. You cannot access Realm from background to pick an article in your prepareForSegue: method and then use the article in the main thread in ReadArticleViewController. 
Why are you trying to pass the article in background anyway?

Comment: I wish it were that simple, but I am accessing the article in the background thread in the ReadArticleViewController also. I think the problem is that it can choose a different background thread for each view controller, or something like that.

Comment: By "it", I mean Grand Central Dispatch.

Comment: This answer is correct. `Async.background {}` will run on a GCD queue obtained by calling `dispatch_get_global_queue`, which isn't guaranteed to return the same thread every time. Even if it did, setting the property on `ReadArticleViewController` in the background is counter-productive because it won't be able to be accessed from the main thread. For these reasons, you should just set the property in the main thread. Thanks for the nice answer, Iman!